# Clojure with-local-vars in closure

Tags: clojure, closures

In Clojure, are the variables defined through `with-local-vars` accessible through closure?

Consider the below example:

```
(defn foo []
      (with-local-vars [bar 10]
           (fn [] @bar)))

((foo))
```

Result is the following:

```
#object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x131f68d8 "Unbound: #<Var: --unnamed-->"]
```

(Instead, I was expecting to get `10`.)

C.f. with the following:

```
(defn foo []
     (with-local-vars [bar 10] @bar))
(foo)
```

Result: `10`.

Based on the [documentation](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-local-vars), it is not clear to me, if it is valid to use local vars in Clojure as above, but I would suspect the answer is no. Can you please confirm this (or refute, and explain what I'm doing wrong in the first example)? And if my supposition is clear (i.e., that local vars cannot be used in the closure), then explain what is the reason for that?

EDIT: for the records, [this is the problem I was trying to solve](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154433/function-to-log-arguments-and-return-value-of-any-function-in-clojure).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for `with-local-vars` doesn't seem particularly clear here. It just says it creates thread-local bindings for the variables, but doesn't say anything about what happens to them when you exit the `with-local-vars` scope.

In contrast, the [`with-bindings` documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/with-bindings) explicitly says that the thread-local bindings are popped when leaving that scope.

If you look at the source code, you can see that both `with-local-vars` and `with-bindings` are implemented using the same basic mechanisms (`pushThreadBindings` and `popThreadBindings`), which suggests they should have almost identical behavior.

So yes, you're right, you cannot expect the `with-local-vars` values captured in a closure to work outside of the `with-local-vars` scope. However, Clojure provides the [`bound-fn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bound-fn) mechanism specifically for building this type of closure, capturing all of the current thread-local bindings:

```
(def foo (with-local-vars [bar 10] (fn [] @bar)))
(foo)
; => #object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x60063e12 "Unbound: #<Var: --unnamed-->"]

(def baz (with-local-vars [bar 10] (bound-fn [] @bar)))
(baz)
; => 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this seems to be indeed the right way of using local variables in the closure. It is nice to learn something new :) Unluckily, though it does not solve my original problem, as it seems that the value of the local variable is "reset", with each invocation of the returned function (see also the linked CodeReview question in the EDIT for details).

Comment: @Attilio - It's not clear to me what your expected behavior is (in your other question). What if you just replace the `with-local-vars` in your `logfun` definition with `(let [depth (atom 0)] ...)` instead? Does that yield the behavior you're looking for? If not, you can try moving the `let` *outside* the `defn logfun` (which will allow `logfun` to close over `depth` without making it a global definition).